# Custom buttons to be able to track Logins and Log Out times

Tags: custom-button, custom-field, home-page-component

I´m pretty new to Salesforce, and I´ve been looking all over the forums on how to do it. I´ve learned quite a bit on what it´s possible, and what´s not.

I want to be able to keep a record on when everybody from the company is login in to Salesforce. I know that salesforce only tracks logins and wont keep track of log outs.

I was thinking of creating 2 custom buttons or custom fields, one that everyone has to click for Login and one for Log out, before going out right on the Salesforce homepage. I think it should be pretty simple and easy to do. But, since I´m new to this I have no idea where and how to do it, I wanted to know if anyone here could help me with this.

I asked on the Success.Salesforce Questions. And was told to use the Event Monitoring. But, when I was looking into it, I saw that it is not available on the Salesforce Pro Edition, which is the one we have.

Thanks,